# Draw a diagonal line between two points with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to draw a diagonal line with CSS and JS between to elements like this.

[image]

I have two divs that I know both of their left and top coordinates.

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='point' style='left: 40px; top: 40px;'></div>
  <div class='point' style='left: 260px; top: 120px;'></div>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```

But how to calculate rotation degree and height value here?

```js
const point1 = document.getElementsByClassName('point')[0]
const point2 = document.getElementsByClassName('point')[1]
const line = document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0]

const lineLeft = parseInt(point1.style.left) + point1.clientWidth
const lineTop = parseInt(point1.style.top) + point1.clientHeight

line.style.left = `${lineLeft}px`
line.style.top = `${lineTop}px`
line.style.height = '?'
line.style.transform = 'rotate(?deg)'
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/ozgrozer/pen/WNRoJJd)'s the CodePen version of it.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but this might be easier with SVG elements instead of CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to do this via CSS and Javascript, it is possible but not ideal. You'll have to do some extra work to calculate the angle between the points and the distance between your points. Take a look at the sample below:

```js
const point1 = document.getElementsByClassName('point')[0]
const point2 = document.getElementsByClassName('point')[1]
const line = document.getElementsByClassName('line')[0]

// Find the points based off the elements left and top
var p1 = {x: point1.offsetLeft, y: point1.offsetTop};
var p2 = {x: point2.offsetLeft, y: point2.offsetTop};

// Get distance between the points for length of line
var a = p1.x - p2.x;
var b = p1.y - p2.y;
var length = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b );

// Get angle between points
var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;

// Get distance from edge of point to center
var pointWidth = point1.clientWidth / 2;
var pointHeight = point1.clientWidth / 2;

// Set line distance and position
// Add width/height from above so the line starts in the middle instead of the top-left corner
line.style.width = length + 'px';
line.style.left = (p1.x + pointWidth)+ 'px';
line.style.top = (p1.y + pointHeight) + 'px';

// Rotate line to match angle between points
line.style.transform = "rotate(" + angleDeg + "deg)";
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 320px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.point {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #555;
}
.line {
  position: absolute;
  height:2px;
  background-color: #d63030;
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='point' style='left: 40px; top: 40px;'></div>
  <div class='point' style='left: 260px; top: 120px;'></div>
  <div class='line'</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! like zero298 said, its usually better to do this kind of thing in a canvas or using SVG, but sometimes that's not possible. Good luck!